# Recursive program for generating and printing all permutations of the numbers 1, 2, ..., n for given integer number n

Tags: java, recursion, combinatorics

I've just written code for generating all permutations of the numbers from 1 to n in Java. It seems to work, but I think it's a bit more complex than it needs to be.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ProblemFour {
    private static int n;

    private static void printResult(int[] result) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        // I am using Hashset<> to avoid repetitions
        Integer[] nums = new Integer[result.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            nums[i] = result[i];
        }

        Collections.addAll(set, nums);
        if(set.size() == n) System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
    }

    private static void permute(int[] result, int index) {
        if (index == result.length) {
            printResult(result);
            return;
            // Recursion bottom
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            result[index] = i;
            permute(result, index+1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("From 1 to: ");
        n = input.nextInt();

        int[] result = new int[n];

        permute(result, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Single responsibility principle

Think about the possible reuse of your code. More specifically, the `permute` method. Do you think that the caller will **always** want to print out the result? Right now storing the permutations in a variable is impossible, so I cannot use this as a building block for bigger programs. What about `printResult` it does not only print the result, it also takes care of duplicates.

In general each method does many things, even asking for global variables around the class (`printResult` accesses `n`)

I would write follow this stub:

```
public class Permutation extending Array {
    public static Sequence[Sequence[Any]] permutations(Sequence[Any] array) {
        // implementation 
    }
}

public class PermutationUptoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int upperLimit = (new Scanner(System.in)).nextInt()
        System.out.println(Range(1, upperLimit).toArray().permutations().join("\n"));
}
```

You see that I wrote this in pseudo-code, but the main concept is that now you can import the `Permutation` class from anywhere and call it and reuse the result.

The application class just handles input and output and generates the range of numbers.